# smaller runtime data structures and faster code for unique _ptr compared to shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

For unique_ptr the type of deleter is part of the smart pointer, but how does that help compiler to generate smaller runtime data structures and faster code for unique _ptr compared to shared_ptr ?

Comment: Maybe because the overhead of shared_ptr has nothing to do with the deleter and more because of the thread safe refcounting?

Answer (score 1):

The deleters are not what is being referred to here.

`shared_ptr<>` needs to allocate (among other things) two additional numbers for each allocated object (strong and weak reference counts).

if `std::make_shared()` is used, they'll get stored with the object itself, otherwise, there will need to be a separate allocation for it.

Furthermore, keep in mind that `unique_ptr<>` can make use of empty class optimization to eliminate any overhead for non-stateful deleters.

gcc, at the very least, appears to do so (at least with `std::default_delete`):
https://godbolt.org/g/nbENL7